# what is a split brain , when one zookeeper server fail from total 3 zookeepers

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

We have 3 zookeepers servers, and 6 Kafka machines. What could be when one zookeeper server fail, and we have now only two zookeeper servers, what is the chance to get "split brain"?

As I understand when we get a split brain, then the two zookeepers that still alive actually not working as should be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In ZooKeeper, an even number of peers is supported, but it is normally not used because an even sized ensemble requires, proportionally, more peers to form a quorum than an odd sized ensemble requires. For example, an ensemble with 4 peers requires 3 to form a quorum, while an ensemble with 5 also requires 3 to form a quorum. Thus, an ensemble of 5 allows 2 peers to fail and still maintain quorum, and thus is more fault tolerant than the ensemble of 4, which allows only 1 down peer.

So in your case with 3 ensemble, it will support only 1 node failure, as with remaining 2 , it can't form a quorum

Comment: ok I agree that 3 nodes will support 1 fail , but when we ave two machine while one of them is fail is it possible to get split brain on the two machines? , and this is miens also kind of fail?

Comment: second , what you think should be the number of the zookeeper server when we have 20 kafka machines?  , what is the best zookeeper number - 3 or 5 ?

Comment: @Judy 5, but no more than 7 is the rule of thumb for larger clusters. And it's not only failures to consider, but also maintenance and upgrades. Or in the cloud, spread over availability zones (which is one fault domain) in case a data center is unavailable